# Code detection by error when including 3 images right after each other

Tags: bug, images, error-message

In Stack Overflow, when including 3 images right after each other like:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVoEj.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yP1d.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyXll.jpg
```

It generates the error:

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. ...

in the error box:

[image]

For some reason, this error box does not occur when trying to reproduce in "Meta Stack Overflow".

An example question is created in Stack Overflow at [Example of 3 images right after each other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45572339/3989931), where the space between 2nd and 3rd image can be removed to see the problem, since the error does not occur when using:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]
```

It took some debugging before I figured out the problem, and it looks like a bug in Stack Overflow.

Comment: It could be because users like to post code as images and generally those images are right next to each other.  Does it work if you put some text in between them?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Yes it works if there is for example a blank line between 2nd and 3rd; I have updated the question with this info.

Comment: Thanks, looks like a duplicate, but also looks like a bug that has not been fixed 1 year, 7 months ago ;-)

Comment: So, the bug is that if you try to post a question that consists of only three images, you get an error? That is not a bug...

Comment: @CodyGray: No, the bug is that having 3 images right after each other anyware in a "real" question will generate the error box.  When I encountered this problem I did not try to break the system, but actually wrote a question, and by accident hit this this issue, which took me some time to debug.  See example at https://stackoverflow.com/q/45572339/3989931.

Comment: Do we have a situation where we SHOULD have 3 pics back to back? I'd say if you can find a question that would benefit from three pics like this, it would be better than having to create a fake question.... Right now, the only example of why it would be needed is... an example showing what's breaking, not a real question.

Comment: @Patrice: So 2 pics back to back is OK, but 3 pics back to back generates an error box telling that code in the question is wrongly formatted.  For me that sounds like a bug, not a feature ;-)

Comment: @EquipDev I never said anything about that. What I said is that, if the only instance you have of "a question needing three images back 2 back" is "I asked this question to show three pics back 2 back is an issue" then maybe we don't NEED three pics back 2 back. I am not saying it's not a bug. I'm saying it might not be worth fixing.

Comment: @Patrice: No, you did not. I just took the opportunity to air my opinion, that if a design "issue" is encountered several times by independent people, then the design is flawed and should be fixed, rather than expecting people to adapt to the flawed design. But since the "issue" I encountered is old news, my guess is that it won't be fixed, but I am willing to bet that more questions on this are posted later, and more good people will waste time marking those as duplicates...